# Percentage of non-empty values by rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have this dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

d =  {"A" : [3,4,7,6,5,8,None,4,7],
      "B" : ['a',None,'d',None,'j','u','k','k','z'],
      "C" : [4,None,8,4,8,None,2,7,None],
      "D" : [None,9,5,None,2,5,3,None,7],
      "E": ['m','n','l',None,'s','g','s','u','a']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

################################

     A     B    C    D     E
0  3.0     a  4.0  NaN     m
1  4.0  None  NaN  9.0     n
2  7.0     d  8.0  5.0     l
3  6.0  None  4.0  NaN  None
4  5.0     j  8.0  2.0     s
5  8.0     u  NaN  5.0     g
6  NaN     k  2.0  3.0     s
7  4.0     k  7.0  NaN     u
8  7.0     z  NaN  7.0     a
```

What I need is a dictionary, which shows me all the possible combinations of columns with the percentage of empty (or filled) rows, something like this e.g.:

```py
result = {2/9:["A","B","C","D","E"],
          2/9:["A","B","C","E"],
          ...,
          1/9:["A","C"]}
```

I've added also a little image to illustrate my problem:

[image]

This would help me to proper slice and dice the dataframe according to the coverage of non-empty values. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mask the data and you can groupby an count the rows with `size`:

```
out = (df.notnull()
         .groupby(list(df)).size()
         .div(len(df))
      )
print(out.reset_index(name='pct'))
```

Output (`False` indicates a null value, `True` indicates a non-null)

```
       A      B      C      D      E       pct
0  False   True   True   True   True  0.111111
1   True  False  False   True   True  0.111111
2   True  False   True  False  False  0.111111
3   True   True  False   True   True  0.222222
4   True   True   True  False   True  0.222222
5   True   True   True   True   True  0.222222
```

If you want a dictionary, you can try:

```
{
    tuple(df.columns[list(idx)]):val for idx, val in out.iteritems()
}
```

Output:

```
{('B', 'C', 'D', 'E'): 0.1111111111111111,
 ('A', 'D', 'E'): 0.1111111111111111,
 ('A', 'C'): 0.1111111111111111,
 ('A', 'B', 'D', 'E'): 0.2222222222222222,
 ('A', 'B', 'C', 'E'): 0.2222222222222222,
 ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'): 0.2222222222222222
}
```

Comment: This is brillant! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html):

```
out = df.notna().value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Output:

```
A      B      C      D      E    
True   True   False  True   True     0.222222
              True   False  True     0.222222
                     True   True     0.222222
False  True   True   True   True     0.111111
True   False  False  True   True     0.111111
              True   False  False    0.111111
dtype: float64
```